# ProgressBar control cannot be load (Library not registered)

Tags: vba, libraries, powerpoint

I am trying to add a progress bar to my User form but it is giving me "Library not registered" error. What I do is the following:

First I add the progress bar to the toolbox from Tools -> Additional controls

[image]

I choose the progressBar from Toolbox options and try to put it in the userForm

[image]

It gives me the error:

[image]

Apparently I have to add a Library from Tools -> References but I don't know which one is the one that is needed. I google it and I found that the MSCOMCTL.OCX could be the one that I needed but I add this one and I already have the same error.

Someone know which one is the correct?

EDIT

I put my references list so you can see what I am using:

[image]

Comment: Please help us reproduce your problem if you want us to help you solve it. http://sscce.org/index.html

Comment: I put more explanation... hope that this will be enough to understand what is going on and to reproduce it.

Comment: are you using the 32 bit or 64 bit Office 365 version? The reason I ask is, I'm pretty sure a lot of the controls in MSCOMCTL.OCX aren't supported in 64-bit office installs (http://www.slyman.org/blog/2010/11/64-bit-windows-7office-2010-migration-experiences/) .

Answer (score 1):

you need a reference to Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) to utilize the Progress bar.   This should have been added when you selected the progress bar.

EDIT
Register it.

open a command prompt with admin creds and type in

```
regsvr32 /s MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

EDIT#2
on a 64bit machine under admin creds in a command prompt.

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

Comment: I have that one already checked... I will put my references list so you can see what I have. Maybe is another thing missing.

Comment: if you create a brand new workbook, create a new form and add just the progress bar, do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes I opened a blank powerpoint presentation and create a userForm. When I tried to add the progress bar it gave me the error

Comment: do you have IE 10 installed?

Comment: I have IE 11 installed. My computer have a windows 8.1 with office 365

Comment: install the VB6 runtime files: link here http://support.microsoft.com/gp/vbruntime

Comment: In case anyone ever returns to this concept, it worked in Windows 7 & Windows 10 if you then do 1 more step after the 2 above on a fresh install.  You must run vb6 or the DevEnv.exe elevated as Admin, only once to get the registrations setup in the Reg.  Once done, you can run from then on as your normal user and they'll show up on the Tools bar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VB6 or some other programming language installed on the system?  One that shipped with MS Windows Common Controls 6 (SP6)?

IIRC some of these controls can run on any system so long as they're properly installed and registered but can only be used to design/create code on a system where the language they shipped with is installed.

Others controls are compatible with VB but not VBA forms.

With very little extra work, you can create a reasonable progress bar from two text boxes or labels and a bit of code.  Lighter weight, requires no installation/registration at the user end.